# SelectedValue of a ComboBox Universal Apps Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, combobox, windows-phone-8.1, selecteditem

I am trying to get the value from a select box and can compare it to a string. Thus the value of another combobox should be changed.

```
<!-- Combo 1 -->

<ComboBox x:Name="Combo1"  Header="Combo1" SelectionChanged="Combo1_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 1" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 2"/>
</ComboBox>

<!--Combo 2 -->

<ComboBox x:Name="Combo2"  Header="Combo2" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 3" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 4"/>
</ComboBox>
```

And the function SelectionChanged

```
private void Combo1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((ComboBoxItem)Combo1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "Value 2")
    {
        Combo2.Items.Add("Value 5");
    }
}
```

I tried some previous options including the above example, but showed an `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Could you point in your code where the `NullReferenceException` come from (probably with the top of the stacktrace)? Thanks.

Comment: Romasz solution its work. Thank you for help. And the NullReferenceException come from ((ComboBoxItem)Combo1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString()

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting the exception just when your app starts - during *InitializeComponent()* of your Page - if you debug it, you will see that before initializing has ended, the element with name `Combo1` is *null*, so you will get exception by calling `Combo1.SelectedItem`.

Try like this:

```cs
private void Combo1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = (sender as ComboBox);
    if ((comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "Value 2")
    {
        Combo2.Items.Add("Value 5");
    }
}
```

Comment: @vtncgustavo In that case, could you accept it? That is the suggested way to signal that this problem has been solved. Thanks.